# syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '-' (syntax)

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-secrets

I have two environmental variables defined which are working fine. Apart from this, I have one JSON object serviceAccount which stored in manually created secret firebase-connector. As soon as I add this second part I got an error. I followed syntax but it's not working.

[][1]
[1]: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables

```
syntax error: expected <block end>, but found '-' (syntax)
```

test.yml

```
    env:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: pns_usr
      JAVA_OPTIONS: >-
        -server -Xmx700M -Xms700M -XX:NewSize=500M -XX:MaxNewSize=500M
        -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
      - name: PNS_SERVICEACCOUNT
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: firebase-connector
            key: serviceAccount
```

FirebaseService.java

```
 @Value("${pns.serviceaccount}")
    String serviceAccountValue;
```

application.properties

```
pns.serviceaccount=${PNS_SERVICEACCOUNT}
spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
```

Comment: is this your values.yaml file? your `- name: PNS_SERVICEACCOUNT` block should be in `containers:` section of your template

Comment: updated question with details

Comment: can you post your full drone.yml and deployment.yaml

Comment: I think this information should be enough. because everything is working except adding new way of secret -name. cant post security reason

Comment: if your drone.yaml is file where you keep your values, it's the wrong place to define `secretKeyRef`, this whole `- name: PNS_SERVICEACCOUNT` should be under the `containers:` section of your deployment.

Comment: I have added a secret config in Openshift. config name is firebase-connector and the key is serviceAccount which holds value inside config. How can I access this value within application?

Comment: my bad. the filename is to my environment following more like this. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-environment-variables